# receive data from server to a regular js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to send info from my server-side to my client-side, I need to do this so I could show a message in my HTML file.

I want to get the 'newUser' from the server-side (node.js) to my client-side. I send newUser in the server so I could get it in my regular js file.

```
res.status(200).send(newUser);
```

which way can I do this?

I have tried:

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xhttp);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (xhttp.responseText !== null) { //exist
            document.getElementById("exist").style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('exist').style.display = "none";
            }, 3000);
            console.log("exist");
        } else { //not exist
            console.log("not exist");
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/newUser");
xhttp.send();
```

but xhttp didn't give me the 'userName' but I got this in my console:

> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
>   onabort: null
>   onerror: null
>   onload: null
>   onloadend: null
>   onloadstart: null
>   onprogress: null
>   onreadystatechange: null
>   ontimeout: null
>   readyState: 1
>   response: ""
>   responseText: ""
>   responseType: ""
>   responseURL: ""
>   responseXML: null
>   status: 0
>   statusText: ""
>   timeout: 0
>   upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
>   withCredentials: false
>   **proto**: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload instead

Comment: @Juan Carrey I am only getting the info that I just send from the client not the server.

Comment: Did you check Network tab to see if the request was actually made ?

And again, use onload instead of readystate change:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: the request was done and I still get XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 0, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: ƒ ()
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: null
readyState: 1
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseURL: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
withCredentials: false
in the console